# How to disable previous button in Android softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have developed an application for the slate 21 hp device. I wrote code for the next button of the soft keyboard and it is working fine. However, on long press on next button it shows prev button but when I click on it, it performs some unusual way. I researched and found that we can use either next or prev, so I want to know is: when the device is showing prev, is there any way to hide the prev button?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding code will help people understand your problem better and attempt solving it.

Answer (score 0):

you must change `android:imeOptions="actionNone"` in your edittext or other component

Comment: but if I will do this ,I will not show next option also right?I want next to be there but it should not show prev over it when I long press on next button.